# Pagination-asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problems in displaying page on how to include the prev and next link...
I am using ASP.Net MVC 4 using these codes:

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        @for (int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.PagesCount; i++)
        {
            <text>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", new { pagee = i })</li>
            </text>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
int offset = 15;

int pagecount = ((pagee - 1) * offset);

int totalPages = 0;
int totalItems = 0;

try
{       
    totalItems = requestform.Count();
    while (totalItems > 0)
    {
        totalItems -= 15;
        totalPages++;
    }
    ViewBag.PagesCount = totalPages;
    return View(requestform.Skip(pagecount).Take(offset).ToList());
}
catch
{
    while (totalItems > 0)
    {
        totalItems -= 15;
        totalPages++;
    }
    ViewBag.PagesCount = totalPages;
    return View(requestform.Skip(pagecount).Take(offset).ToList());
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the problem you're having?

Comment: this might help you out for paging : [link](http://yassershaikh.com/custom-efficient-paging-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-skip-and-take-linq-methods/)

Comment: i've tried it already using IPageList.MVC but its not working on my project with several tabs....

Answer (score 2):

What do you say about this little extension [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) ?

Answer (score 0):

To add paging to page, you'll start by installing the PagedList NuGet package. Then you'll make additional changes in the Index method and add paging links to the Index view

Please check this link 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @subinpanicker-it's working on a plain project...but when i tried to use it on my project with several tabs, it's not working....T_T...please help me with this...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend also PagedList just add it via NuGet package manager and then,

modify your controller to look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            var dbtable = db.DbTable.Include(s => s.ID).OrderBy(s => s.StyleName); //ensure records are sorted.
            if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            int pageSize = 2;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(dbtable.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

in view replace:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMvcApplication.Models.dbtable>
```

with

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyMvcApplication.Models.dbtable>
```

replace code that looks like

```
    <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </th>
```

with

```
<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ID)
        </th>
```

at the end of the page after the `</table>` tag add this:

```
<div>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1})
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new {page = Model.PageNumber - 1})
    }
    else{
     @:<<
     @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev   
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new {page = Model.PageNumber + 1})
        @Html.Raw(" "); 
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new {page = Model.PageCount})
    }
    else{
     @:Next >
     @Html.Raw(" ")
@:>>   
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page })` to automatically generate paging links for you...

Answer (score 0):

recently i found with **cool controls**, tooltip, first, next, last, previous check this [mvc 4 paging nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Paging/), demo [web page](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/)